# simple jqgrid with php script return json data from php

Tags: php, jqgrid

where I get a sample of jqgrid with php script. where as php return json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example on the jqgrid web site.

http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx

If you use firebug you can see the JSON response sent to the plugin from PHP.

Comment: @nazmul hasan: you should click on "PHP" button or use [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/loading_data/million_sql/default.php#PHPCode) link directly. You should take in the consideration that the code is from **the commercial version** of jqGrid. Do you use the commercial version or [the free open source](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) JavaScript version of jqGrid?